# Get stocks historical price: get_data_yahoo or yfinance

Tags: python, pandas-datareader, yfinance

I am a little bit confused about get_data_yahoo from pandas_datareader and yfinance.
I saw some script online that uses get_data_yahoo but anyway they import yfinance and launch the function yf.pdr_override() right after.

But if I just do:

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import datetime as dt

start = dt.datetime(2014,1,1)
end = dt.datetime.now()
pd = pdr.get_data_yahoo("FB", start, end)
pd
```

it looks to work perfectly, but probably I miss a piece, I do not know.

Instead, if I want to use yfinance, I just do:

```
import yfinance as yf

fb = yf.Ticker("FB")
fb.history(period="max")
```

and it works just fine also.

Nowadays which is the method that you consider more reliable?
Is there any reason to import both and use only get_data_yahoo?

Comment: What do you mean "miss a piece"? Both call the same API and both are in a pandas dataframe

Comment: @OneCricketeer Even if both of them call the same API, I do not understand why get_data_yahoo works even without calling the yf.pdr_override(). So I do not know what the override is for. Thanks